# Adjusting <td> height with CSS

Tags: html, css

I thought this'd be very simple.
All I want is to set the height of td and th cells according to the CSS below.

```
    td, th{ height: 18px;
            width: 16px;
            padding: 34px;
            border: solid black 4px;
    }
```

I have tried `overflow: hidden`.

I have tried `height: 100%`.

I have tried `white-space: nowrap`.

PLEASE tell me there's something other than `<td><div></div></td>`

No matter what I do, the td and th heights are always 0px.

How can I set those heights to 18px?

Comment: Setting a pixel height works fine for me, maybe there's another portion of CSS interfering. https://jsfiddle.net/fqhhp7vt/

Comment: My code does not do as either of yours are doing.
td.height just keeps setting itself to 0.